EVE2 Asset Builder for Linux Ubuntu
Is there an alternative GUI/Command line software to replace the Windows-only Asset Builder by Bridgetek?

What functionality you expect?

@RomeoNinov the same of the original application. But in detail, at least the conversion of jpg/png to C code to be used with cmd_inflate

I am sorry, do not get it. Convert image to C program? Can you please clarify?

Do you want to load image in the memory of FT8xx?

It's the purpose of that application. If you want to show images on a EVE2 display, you can read binary data from a C file: see https://github.com/RudolphRiedel/FT800-FT813/blob/5.x/examples/EVE_Test_ESP32_PlatformIO/src/tft_data.c

Exactly, but the EAB application helps to create compressed images and convert them directly to C header/source code

From what I understand from the process you should exec two steps:
Step one: convert to proper JPEG format. This can be done with ImageMagick package, available in probably every linux distribution. You should make some tests with parameters to get the proper format.
Step two is to convert the image in hex format to be included in C program. From github project I see it expect:
const uint8_t pic[3391] PROGMEM =
{
    0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe0, 0x0, 0x10, 0x4a, 0x46,....

So you can convert to hex with command:
 xxd -i input.jpg|tee output.c |wc -w

xxd will convert to hex, tee will write to file output.c and also to STDOUT from where wc will count the number of the words (which is the parameter for size of pic array.
And on the end you should copy the number and paste in your code, same for the output.c.
Will short bash code you can authomate most of the work, just need to edit the source and replace from line 26 and below with something like
#include "/path/to/output_with_def.c"


Actually, the number returned by wc is different than the provided size of the array (at the bottom of the .c file. Why?

If you talk about this file: https://github.com/RudolphRiedel/FT800-FT813/blob/5.x/examples/EVE_Test_ESP32_PlatformIO/src/tft_data.c I checked all the 3 inline "files" and the numbers match. Did you copy/include in wc the }; on the end? You should not.

Sorry, I explained it wrong. If I issue xxd -i input.jpg|tee output.c |wc -w on a JPEG image on my computer, it returns a number on the console, i.e. 5522 but in the generated C file, at the end I find: unsigned int image_jpg_len = 5511;

I have no idea what is this record about. The number 5522 should be placed here: const uint8_t pic[5522] PROGMEM = {
